# Opaque Links in Questions

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49001511) contains an opaque link to ...something... on Google Drive. I assume it really is just an image (as the asker claims), but there's *no way* I'm following it to find out.

Now I realize that the user doesn't actually want to link to an image, and in reality seems to have misunderstood how to properly use markdown to insert an escaped link. And let's also ignore for a minute the fact that this isn't a great question to begin with. When I came across the "mystery" link, it raised a more general question for me - how to handle links of this sort. I asked the author to change it, but they elected (or are unable?) to do so. I checked the help center, but it's not clear to me whether or not such links are permitted (when actually useful). Editing or flagging are out, since I don't actually know if policy is being violated here.

So my question is, what's the official SO policy on the sorts of links that are allowed? And how should a user browsing through questions handle this sort of thing?

Comment: In general, it's not against policy to have those links as long as they aren't necessary to understand the question or answer. The post can't require going to a 3rd party link because links break (and in this case users can't trust it in the first place). But there isn't a rule against having a link like that at all as long as it isn't malicious.

Comment: @BSMP I suppose it's that as a long time internet denizen, I tend to assume links of that sort are malicious by default. But if official SO policy differs, then so be it. Note that generally I'm completely unwilling to follow any link that doesn't have a readily apparent domain that I can verify as reasonably trustworthy. So for example a link to `site.com/someresource` where site could be SE, Imgur, BBC, or wherever I'll follow, but some UUID on Google Drive or a bit.ly link is *never* getting clicked.

Comment: That's completely reasonable and I think you did the right thing in asking them to at least use something trustworthy like Imgur.  There just isn't much else you can do if you can't confirm the link actually has something wrong with it. As an aside, if someone just needs 'an' example image, not a specific one, they can use a site like https://placeholder.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no policy against opaque links *per se*, but content that does not follow [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy should be removed or edited.

Guidance is simple - most links are allowed (except spam, malicious and clearly offensive), but question or answer must stand by itself even if all links are broken (imgurl links for images considered to be part of the question).

If to figure out meaning of the question you need to follow a link then such question need to be either improved by inlining necessary information from the link (usually by the author, but sometime can be done by community) or closed as unclear/missing MCVE (author will have they one chance get post reviewed in re-open queue after first edit).

If link is spam, malicious or offensive - please flag post appropriately and moderators will take care of it.

In some cases editing may be appropriate when link is used as just example of data (i.e. convert sample link to text or replace domain with "example.com" - see http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2606.html for more info on sample DNS names). Do not edit clear spam posts - it would slow down removal and waste time in general.

Comment: Thanks for the well written and clear answer! I can't edit since it's meta, would you mind adding something to the effect of "There is no policy against opaque links *per se*, only those that can be confirmed as malicious." since that's the original question that led me to ask?

Comment: @user69513 updated. (I did not know if Meta edit restrictions are different than main, also not very surprised).